# Gitik's work on Shelah's weak hypothesis

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, cardinal-arithmetic, pcf-theory

It seems that Moti Gitik has recently refuted some variants of Shelah's weak hypothesis. For this see the title and abstract of his talk at the [Set Theory, Model Theory and Applications](https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~arkady/Eilat_2018_conference/booklet_Eilat2018/Abstracts_Eilat_2018.pdf) conference.

I am wondering if someone can explain more about the ideas of his proof and the differences with his previous proof of the refutation of the pcf conjecture.

See also the following where the main result seems to be stated:

[image]

Gitik's work is now available: [Extender based forcings with overlapping extenders and negations of the Shelah Weak Hypothesis](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~gitik/EBFOE-5-18.pdf).

Comment: For completeness it might be worth adding the credit on the picture and posting it online (which goes to Assaf Rinot).